# error in the plist when changing a buttons title swift

Tags: ios, swift

Hello I am trying to change a buttons title, I get an error with the `plist` which I don't understand. Please help.

This is the `plist` error I got:

[image: this is the plist error I got.]

This is the code:

```
@IBAction func Helllo(_ sender: UIButton) {
    sender.setTitle("hello", for: UIControlState.normal)
}
```

I don't know what to put for the `for:` parameter?

Comment: It looks like you don't have the correct path for the info.plist file. Follow the path in the error and see if the plist file actually exists there. If not you will need to change the path to your plist to match the real path.

Comment: thx that worked